# Exception while Initializing a Java Instance in Guice

Tags: java, generics, guice

I have created mock classes to explain my issue. Consider this Java class I have in my project.

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class ExampleClass<T> {

private final Class<T> classType;
private ObjectSerializer objectSerializer;

//Constructor
@Inject
public ExampleClass(final Class<T> classType, final ObjectSerializer objectSerializer){
  this.classType = classType;
  this.objectSerializer = objectSerializer;
}

public T randomMethod(String hashKey, String rangeKey){
  return objectSerializer.deserialize(dataBaseHelper.getData(hashKey, rangeKey), classType);
}
```

Assuming I want to initialize the class for the Type ExamplePojo (T is ExamplePojo), I am doing the following for Initializing a Singleton Instance in Guice,

```
public class ExampleModule extends AbstractModule{

@Provides
@Singleton
public ExampleClass<ExamplePojo> provideExampleClass(ObjectSerialization objectSerialization){
  return new ExampleClass<>(ExamplePojo.class, objectSerialization);
}
}
```

When I try to initialize my server, I get the following exception.

```
 [java] 1) java.lang.Class<T> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
 [java]   at com.service.ExampleClass.<init>(ExampleClass.java:XX)
            ...
            ...

 [java]
 [java] 1 error
 [java]     at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466)
 [java]     at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
 [java]     at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
 [java]     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
 [java]     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
 [java]     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
 [java]     at com.amazon.f1service.F1Service.main(F1Service.java:33)
```

Comment: Guice can't deal with `<T>` because of type erasure.

Comment: So isn't there a way to use Guice for Generics in this scenario? Since I know the class type before initializing, shouldn't it be possible for me to initialize the class?

Comment: If you're using a `@Provides` method to provide the binding, then you don't need an `@Inject` constructor. Remove the annotation from the constructor and you'll still be able to inject `ExampleClass<ExamplePojo>`. You just won't be able to inject `ExampleClass<T>` for an arbitrary T.

Comment: Having both Provides and Inject is causing the issue you mean?